# How do I access and update nested dictionary?

Tags: python, list, nested, tuples, dictionary

How do I access these key values in the nested dict?

```
word = {('o', 'm'): {'e': 3,'a': 1}}
```

Comment: The former isn't valid. Lists can't have keys and values, just a sequence of values. If you want a dict, use a dict. You would access them as normal: `word['o', 'm']['e']` or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

You can answer yourself:

```
>>> # you don't have key and values in lists, that's why you should use a dict.
>>> word = {('o', 'm'): ['e': 3,'a': 1]}
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> word = {('o', 'm'): {'e': 3,'a': 1}}
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
['e': 3,'a': 1]
```

Is not a valid `list` or `dict`, as written.  If you want a list of dicts for whatever reason, you must write:

```
[{'e': 3},{'a': 1}]
```

But these are inferior to simply using a dict, as in your second example.

---

> how do I access these key values in the nested list of dict?

Now, you'll get another dict after access the first one, so from

```
word = {('o', 'm'): {'e': 3,'a': 1}}
print word['o','m'].keys()
#['a', 'e']
print word['o','m']['e']
#3
```